# Websocket with Springboot in a clustered environment

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, spring-websocket

We want to implement websocket in a spring boot clustered environment. We are using JWT for authentication. I understand that we can use ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ as the stomp broker. But we are already using redis and can we some how use redis for that as we do not want to add an additional overhead of maintaining another messaging service?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [redis PubSub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

An introduction about PubSub:

> Pub/Sub
>
> SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE and PUBLISH implement the Publish/Subscribe messaging paradigm where (citing Wikipedia) senders (publishers) are not programmed to send their messages to specific receivers (subscribers). Rather, **published messages are characterized into channels, without knowledge of what (if any) subscribers there may be. Subscribers express interest in one or more channels, and only receive messages that are of interest, without knowledge of what (if any) publishers there are.** This decoupling of publishers and subscribers can allow for greater scalability and a more dynamic network topology.